# How get only mobile numbers in contact

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, phone-number

I have the below code to get contact name and number. How to get only mobile numbers and name in contact? A name in contact may have a few numbers. How to get mobile numbers for a name?

```
 ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
 Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
 while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
 }
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber this library to verify the phone no is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code. Work for me.

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
                Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                        >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME

        };
private static final String[] PROJECTION_PHONE =
        {
                Phone.NUMBER
        };
private static final String SELECTION_PHONE = Phone.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?";

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> contacts = new HashMap<>();

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, null, null, null); //get contacts
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                            >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String lookUpKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) { //check if has numbers
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION_PHONE, SELECTION_PHONE,
                        new String[]{lookUpKey}, null); //get contacts phone numbers
                ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phone = pCur.getString(0);
                    phones.add(phone);
                }
                contacts.put(name, phones);
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE` column to determine the type of the number:

```
int type = phones.getInt(phones.
    getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

if(type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.
        getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                       if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
            {
                // Query phone here. Covered next
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null); 
                while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                         String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         Log.i("Number", phoneNumber);
                        } 
                phones.close(); 
            }

        }
    }
```

**You will have to ask for this permission:**

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"